# Centering a Column Using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" id="buttonList">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><button id="homeBtn" type="button" class="smallMarginB headerButton active btn btn-sm btn-primary">Home</button></li>
                <li><button id="aboutBtn" type="button" class="smallMarginB headerButton btn btn-sm btn-primary">About</button></li>
                <li><button id="servicesBtn" type="button" class="smallMarginB headerButton btn btn-sm btn-primary">Services</button></li>
                <li><button id="transBtn" type="button" class="smallMarginB headerButton btn btn-sm btn-primary">Transformations</button></li>
                <li><button id="testBtn" type="button" class="smallMarginB headerButton btn btn-sm btn-primary">Testimonials</button></li>
                <li><button id="contactBtn" type="button" class="smallMarginB headerButton btn btn-sm btn-primary">Contact</button></li>
                <li><button id="faqBtn" type="button" class="smallMarginB headerButton btn btn-sm btn-primary">FAQ</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It simply shows buttons in a single column. I want it to be centered no matter the users resolution. I have tried using offesets but for odd resolutions it doesn't work (ex. resolution is 1366px). I have also tried adding col-centered and margin: auto with no success.

Comment: Try adding a class with `text-align:center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `class="text-center"` to div col element:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 text-center" id="buttonList">
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. Is there a reason text-center works when center-block and margin: auto; didn't?

Comment: margin: auto works in block elements while text-align:center works for inline elements. In this case, your items are display: inline-block. I hope this helps another time.
Excuse my English, I speak Spanish :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto` for horizontal alignment;

`margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto`, for vertical alignment

or

`margin:auto` for both.

Comment: I have tried that as well. Some reason it only shifts the column slightly the the right (about 5px)